# Qualcomm Atheros QCA6174 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter [168c:003e] (rev 32) can't enable wi-fi

Tags: 16.04, networking, drivers, wireless

I've just installed `Ubuntu 16.04 LTS` (kernel version 
`4.8.0-36-generic`) on new notebook with `Qualcomm Atheros QCA6174 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter [168c:003e] (rev 32)` and it doesn't work.

I found the solution in Internet but it doesn't work for me.
That what I've done:

1. downloaded drivers from this repository:
   https://github.com/kvalo/ath10k-firmware
2. copied this drivers into `/lib/firmware/ath10k/QCA6174` directory
3. `sudo cp /lib/firmware/ath10k/QCA6174/firmware-4.bin_WLAN.RM.2.0-00180-QCARMSWPZ-1 /lib/firmware/ath10k/QCA6174/firmware-4.bin`
4. reload

But wi-fi still doesn't work. When I trying to enadle wi-fi in settings, I cant't do this.

This is the output of `dmesg | grep ath10k` command:

```
[   10.040200] ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: pci irq msi oper_irq_mode 2 irq_mode 0 reset_mode 0
[   10.548072] ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: Direct firmware load for ath10k/pre-cal-pci-0000:02:00.0.bin failed with error -2
[   10.548079] ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: Direct firmware load for ath10k/cal-pci-0000:02:00.0.bin failed with error -2
[   10.591818] ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: qca6174 hw3.2 target 0x05030000 chip_id 0x00340aff sub 17aa:0827
[   10.591823] ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: kconfig debug 0 debugfs 1 tracing 1 dfs 0 testmode 0
[   10.592326] ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: firmware ver WLAN.RM.2.0-00180-QCARMSWPZ-1 api 5 features wowlan,ignore-otp,no-4addr-pad crc32 75dee6c5
[   10.820021] ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: board_file api 2 bmi_id N/A crc32 07ee144e
[   12.984484] ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: htt-ver 3.26 wmi-op 4 htt-op 3 cal otp max-sta 32 raw 0 hwcrypto 1
[   13.587814] ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0 wlp2s0: renamed from wlan0
[  215.900218] ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: pci irq msi oper_irq_mode 2 irq_mode 0 reset_mode 0
[  216.178456] ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: Direct firmware load for ath10k/pre-cal-pci-0000:02:00.0.bin failed with error -2
[  216.178465] ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: Direct firmware load for ath10k/cal-pci-0000:02:00.0.bin failed with error -2
[  216.178507] ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: Direct firmware load for ath10k/QCA6174/hw3.0/firmware-5.bin failed with error -2
[  216.178509] ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: could not fetch firmware file 'ath10k/QCA6174/hw3.0/firmware-5.bin': -2
[  216.178713] ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: qca6174 hw3.2 target 0x05030000 chip_id 0x00340aff sub 17aa:0827
[  216.178715] ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: kconfig debug 0 debugfs 1 tracing 1 dfs 0 testmode 0
[  216.179486] ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: firmware ver WLAN.RM.2.0-00180-QCARMSWPZ-1 api 4 features wowlan,ignore-otp,no-4addr-pad crc32 75dee6c5
[  216.243352] ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: board_file api 2 bmi_id N/A crc32 07ee144e
[  218.410241] ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: htt-ver 3.26 wmi-op 4 htt-op 3 cal otp max-sta 32 raw 0 hwcrypto 1
[  218.498078] ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0 wlp2s0: renamed from wlan0
```

This is `lshw` result:

```
   *-network DISABLED
        description: Wireless interface
        product: QCA6174 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter
        vendor: Qualcomm Atheros
        physical id: 0
        bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
        logical name: wlp2s0
        version: 32
        serial: 58:00:e3:f6:bd:6f
        width: 64 bits
        clock: 33MHz
        capabilities: bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
        configuration: broadcast=yes driver=ath10k_pci driverversion=4.8.0-36-generic firmware=WLAN.RM.2.0-00180-QCARMSWPZ-1 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
        resources: irq:320 memory:94000000-941fffff
```

I've also tried to do this:

```
sudo rm /lib/firmware/ath10k/QCA6174/hw3.0/* 2> /dev/null

sudo wget -O /lib/firmware/ath10k/QCA6174/hw3.0/board.bin https://github.com/kvalo/ath10k-firmware/blob/master/QCA6174/hw3.0/board.bin?raw=true

sudo wget -O /lib/firmware/ath10k/QCA6174/hw3.0/board-2.bin https://github.com/kvalo/ath10k-firmware/blob/master/QCA6174/hw3.0/board-2.bin?raw=true

sudo wget -O /lib/firmware/ath10k/QCA6174/hw3.0/firmware-4.bin https://github.com/kvalo/ath10k-firmware/blob/master/QCA6174/hw3.0/firmware-4.bin_WLAN.RM.2.0-00180-QCARMSWPZ-1?raw=true
```

But result was the same.

I can't understand what am I doing wrong.

P.S. Sorry for my english )

UPD:

`rfkill list all` output:

```
0: ideapad_wlan: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: yes
1: ideapad_bluetooth: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: yes
    Hard blocked: yes
2: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: yes
    Hard blocked: no
4: phy1: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

Comment: Please edit to include results for `rfkill list all`

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `rfkill list` terminal command.

Comment: I was looking for a solution to this for my Dell XPS 15 9560 which suffered from WiFi instability, also using the QCA6174 WiFi adapter. I could connect to WiFi, but after about 20-30 minutes it would disconnect until I turned WiFi off and on again. I found [this guide from Dell](https://www.dell.com/support/article/en-us/sln306440/killer-n1535-wireless-firmware-manual-update-guide-for-ubuntu-systems?lang=en) which was very easy to follow, and so far I haven't had any disconnects (I'll update if the problem persists). I can't attest for this working on other systems besides Dell, but the guide

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Run in a terminal

```
sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/ideapad.conf <<< "blacklist ideapad_laptop"
```

and reboot.

And I suggest not to fiddle with the firmware. Also restore the standard package by

```
 sudo apt update
 sudo apt install --reinstall linux-firmware
```

You need to be connected to the internet to do it.

Comment: Do you mean that I could just run just this one command?

Comment: What do you mean? The first command fixed the problem. Too others restore to the default firmware. But if all works you can leave it as it is.

Comment: Thanks, I have no idea, why it works, though it was pain, a lot of pain, thanks it solved my problem too. I added blacklist dell_laptop for my dell latitude 3460

Answer (score 0):

Because you showed us that the command "rfkill list all" provided:

> 0: ideapad_wlan: Wireless LAN
>      Soft blocked: no
>      Hard blocked: yes

A "hard block" is when a physical off switch is enabled. Sometimes there are actual physical switches that move left or right to enable a module or it's an F-key or it's a Function+F key which enables the module.

Find out which it is for your computer then toggle it. Then re-check "rfkill list all" and see if the Hard block is gone. It should say "Hard blocked: no".

Answer (score 0):

I was facing same problem, what i did is:

```
sudo apt install firmware-atheros
sudo reboot
```

Then it worked for me.