# Ubuntu 18.04: Unstable wifi connection with Qualcomm Atheros

Tags: drivers, wireless, network-manager, 18.04, atheros

Dear Ubuntu community,

I am fairly new to Linux but I've been running Ubuntu 16.04 for a year on my Thinkpad. But I am not particularly familiar with the shell or have any developer skills. Even though I had several wifi problems (wifi would randomly disconnect and would not show any network), I managed to live with

```
$ sudo service network-manager restart
```

whenever it would disconnect.

A week ago my internet connection completely stopped working (ethernet and wifi). I couldn't figure out the problem so I took the opportunity to upgrade to Ubuntu 18.04.

Now I am happy with 18.04 but my wifi problem started again. However, the command I was using before doesn't work anymore. It would restart the Network Manager but wifi connections remain not detected. At the moment I fix the issue by rebooting the PC. However, as you can imagine this is quite annoying. It happens three times a day while I am working. So I am having hopes now that someone could help resolve this issue permanently...

Here is some more information about my device:

```
$ lspci | grep Network
05:00.0 Network controller: Qualcomm Atheros QCA6174 802.11ac
Wireless Network Adapter (rev 32)


$ lsusb
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 04f2:b5c0 Chicony Electronics Co., Ltd 
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 0cf3:e300 Atheros Communications, Inc. 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub


$ sudo lshw -class network
*-network                 
   description: Ethernet interface
   product: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
   vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
   physical id: 0
   bus info: pci@0000:04:00.0
   logical name: enp4s0
   version: 10
   serial: c8:5b:76:9f:fa:ca
   size: 10Mbit/s
   capacity: 1Gbit/s
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
   configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=2.3LK-NAPI duplex=half firmware=rtl8168g-3_0.0.1 04/23/13 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=MII speed=10Mbit/s
   resources: irq:125 ioport:c000(size=256) memory:f4204000-f4204fff memory:f4200000-f4203fff
 *-network
   description: Wireless interface
   product: QCA6174 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter
   vendor: Qualcomm Atheros
   physical id: 0
   bus info: pci@0000:05:00.0
   logical name: wlp5s0
   version: 32
   serial: 90:cd:b6:3e:34:8b
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
   configuration: broadcast=yes driver=ath10k_pci driverversion=4.15.0-23-generic firmware=WLAN.RM.4.4.1-00079-QCARMSWPZ-1 ip=35.22.127.120 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
   resources: irq:128 memory:f4000000-f41fffff
```

So I have a Qualcomm wifi card that seems to give problems for many people, but I just cannot figure out how to fix this issue.

I read some similar questions [[1]](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2323812) [[2]](https://askubuntu.com/questions/929027/qualcomm-atheros-qca6174-802-11ac-wireless-network-adapter-168c003e-rev-32) with a firmware problem but I am a bit hesitant to download and install some other firmware. (I've had to set up Ubuntu completely new for three times so far because I messed up something...)

```
$dmesg | grep -i firmware
[    0.028000] Spectre V2 : Enabling Restricted Speculation for firmware calls
[    0.072344] ACPI: [Firmware Bug]: BIOS _OSI(Linux) query ignored
[    2.280571] [drm] Finished loading DMC firmware i915/kbl_dmc_ver1_01.bin (v1.1)
[    3.507593] Bluetooth: hci0: QCA: patch rome 0x302 build 0x138, firmware rome 0x302 build 0x111
[    3.889893] ath10k_pci 0000:05:00.0: Direct firmware load for ath10k/pre-cal-pci-0000:05:00.0.bin failed with error -2
[    3.889916] ath10k_pci 0000:05:00.0: Direct firmware load for ath10k/cal-pci-0000:05:00.0.bin failed with error -2
[    3.909640] ath10k_pci 0000:05:00.0: firmware ver WLAN.RM.4.4.1-00079-QCARMSWPZ-1 api 6 features wowlan,ignore-otp crc32 fd869beb
[    7.648023] psmouse serio2: trackpoint: IBM TrackPoint firmware: 0x0e, buttons: 3/3
```

Then, there were some posts on power management. When I was running 16.04, I tried to turn it off but it didn't solve the issue. And it disconnects frequently even while I'm plugged to energy so I think it's a different problem.

```
$ iwconfig
wlp5s0    IEEE 802.11  ESSID:"MSUnet Guest 3.0"  
Mode:Managed  Frequency:5.24 GHz  Access Point: D8:24:BD:85:A9:7E   
Bit Rate=6 Mb/s   Tx-Power=17 dBm   
Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
Power Management:off
Link Quality=50/70  Signal level=-60 dBm  
Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
Tx excessive retries:0  Invalid misc:0   Missed beacon:0

lo        no wireless extensions.
enp4s0    no wireless extensions.
```

In another question someone asked for this output, if it helps anyone:

```
$ rfkill list all
0: hci0: Bluetooth
Soft blocked: yes
Hard blocked: no
1: tpacpi_bluetooth_sw: Bluetooth
Soft blocked: yes
Hard blocked: no 
2: phy0: Wireless LAN
Soft blocked: no
Hard blocked: no
```

Let me know if I can provide any more details. I hope someone can help me.
Thanks a lot in advance.

Best,
neko