# Wifi cannot be turned on on Lenovo Yoga 910 with Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: wireless, 18.04, lenovo

I am relatively new to Ubuntu, and for the life of me cannot figure out why the WiFi won't switch on. Airplane mode is off seeing as Bluetooth is on, the problem seems only to be in the WiFi. Before installing Ubuntu, the WiFi was working fine in Windows 10. Thanks in advance :)

Edit: the laptop is a Lenovo Yoga 910, with a Qualcomm Aetheros qca6174 wireless adapter

Comment: what is the output of ifconfig and lspci|grep -i net ?

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu! please [edit] the [requested outputs](https://askubuntu.com/q/1062610/#comment1739693_1062610) into your post or better yet, review [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/425180/225694) and collect the data and [edit] your post to include a [pastie](https://paste.ubuntu.com/) to the output resulting from the script.  Thank you for helping us help you!

Comment: Is this a Yoga 910 with 15" display?  If it is, please consider filing a bug report as it isn't fixed upstream yet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a possible duplicate of [This Question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/929027/qualcomm-atheros-qca6174-802-11ac-wireless-network-adapter-168c003e-rev-32)

According to above link you just need to blacklist a particular module from loading, in this case ideapad_laptop. So from the command line run the following command:

```
sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/ideapad.conf <<< "blacklist ideapad_laptop"
```

and reboot.

Comment: Thank you so much, this worked!! I've been on this for hours now, I appreciate the help :))

Comment: You bet! Glad it worked out for you! Welcome to Ubuntu!!!!!!

Comment: Bug reports should have been filed so this could be fixed in the kernel similar to [this](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/next/linux-next.git/commit/drivers/platform/x86/ideapad-laptop.c?id=40c30bbf3377babc4d6bb16b699184236a8bfa27)  as that is how the 13 inch Yoga 910 was fixed