# "No Wi-Fi Adapter found" - Dell XPS 13 on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: wireless, dell, atheros

I've made a fresh install of Ubuntu 18.04 LTS months ago, but this week my internet connection via WiFi has suddenly stopped working (tethering works, though: unstably via USB, rather reliably via Bluetooth, which is how I'm currently connecting to this site).

My device is a Dell XPS13 with Qualcomm Atheros: `lshw -class network` returns

```
   description: Network controller
   product: QCA6174 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter
   vendor: Qualcomm Atheros
   physical id: 0
   bus info: pci@0000:3a:00.0
   version: 32
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list
   configuration: driver=ath10k_pci latency=0
   resources: irq:139 memory:dc000000-dc1fffff
```

so no logical name; when I check the OS' settings I'm told "No Wi-Fi adapter found - Make sure you have a Wi-Fi adapter plugged and turned on", and indeed when I run `ifconfig` I get

```
bnep0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
    inet 192.168.44.124  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.44.255
    inet6 fe80::ea16:24ce:ea72:9208  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
    ether 9c:b6:d0:ed:90:24  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
    RX packets 391  bytes 54441 (54.4 KB)
    RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
    TX packets 644  bytes 97056 (97.0 KB)
    TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

enp0s20f0u2: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
    inet 192.168.42.83  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.42.255
    inet6 fe80::45ba:d529:b72f:ffc8  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
    ether 66:4d:6f:7e:70:65  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
    RX packets 62043  bytes 62840918 (62.8 MB)
    RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
    TX packets 49542  bytes 14115031 (14.1 MB)
    TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
    inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
    inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
    loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
    RX packets 23793  bytes 1773826 (1.7 MB)
    RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
    TX packets 23793  bytes 1773826 (1.7 MB)
    TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

Output of `lsusb`:

```
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 0c45:670c Microdia 
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 04f3:20d0 Elan Microelectronics Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0cf3:e300 Atheros Communications, Inc. 
Bus 001 Device 010: ID 2717:ff80  
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

Any suggestion would be greatly appreciated! No solution found on askubuntu has helped so far - so this is not a duplicate.

---

UPDATE

This is the outcome of `sudo modprobe ath10k_pci && dmesg | grep ath`:

```
[    2.784311] ath10k_pci 0000:3a:00.0: enabling device (0000 -> 0002)
    [    2.786981] ath10k_pci 0000:3a:00.0: pci irq msi oper_irq_mode 2 irq_mode 0 reset_mode 0
[    2.836893] Modules linked in: intel_rapl x86_pkg_temp_thermal intel_powerclamp coretemp kvm_intel kvm ath10k_pci(+) snd_hda_codec_realtek(+) dell_laptop(+) snd_soc_skl irqbypass crct10dif_pclmul crc32_pclmul ghash_clmulni_intel snd_hda_codec_generic pcbc snd_soc_skl_ipc ath10k_core snd_hda_ext_core snd_soc_sst_dsp snd_soc_sst_ipc ath snd_soc_acpi snd_soc_core aesni_intel snd_compress mac80211(OE) ac97_bus aes_x86_64 snd_pcm_dmaengine sch_fq_codel crypto_simd glue_helper snd_hda_intel cryptd btusb uvcvideo(+) snd_hda_codec btrtl dell_wmi intel_cstate videobuf2_vmalloc snd_hda_core dell_smbios intel_rapl_perf videobuf2_memops btbcm snd_hwdep btintel videobuf2_v4l2 dcdbas videobuf2_core bluetooth joydev snd_pcm input_leds hid_multitouch videodev wmi_bmof cfg80211(OE) serio_raw dell_wmi_descriptor snd_seq_midi
[    3.077620] ath10k_pci 0000:3a:00.0: Direct firmware load for ath10k/pre-cal-pci-0000:3a:00.0.bin failed with error -2
[    3.077626] ath10k_pci 0000:3a:00.0: Direct firmware load for ath10k/cal-pci-0000:3a:00.0.bin failed with error -2
[    3.078902] ath10k_pci 0000:3a:00.0: qca6174 hw3.2 target 0x05030000 chip_id 0x00340aff sub 1a56:1535
[    3.078903] ath10k_pci 0000:3a:00.0: kconfig debug 0 debugfs 1 tracing 1 dfs 0 testmode 0
[    3.079273] ath10k_pci 0000:3a:00.0: firmware ver WLAN.RM.4.4.1-00079-QCARMSWPZ-1 api 6 features wowlan,ignore-otp crc32 fd869beb
[    3.143217] ath10k_pci 0000:3a:00.0: board_file api 2 bmi_id N/A crc32 20d869c3
[    3.723620] ath10k_pci 0000:3a:00.0: Unknown eventid: 118809
[    3.726696] ath10k_pci 0000:3a:00.0: Unknown eventid: 90118
[    3.727181] ath10k_pci 0000:3a:00.0: htt-ver 3.47 wmi-op 4 htt-op 3 cal otp max-sta 32 raw 0 hwcrypto 1
[    3.813764] ath: EEPROM regdomain: 0x6c
[    3.813765] ath: EEPROM indicates we should expect a direct regpair map
[    3.813765] ath: Country alpha2 being used: 00
[    3.813766] ath: Regpair used: 0x6c
[    3.813798] Modules linked in: nls_iso8859_1 wl(POE) intel_rapl x86_pkg_temp_thermal intel_powerclamp coretemp kvm_intel kvm ath10k_pci snd_hda_codec_realtek(+) dell_laptop snd_soc_skl irqbypass crct10dif_pclmul crc32_pclmul ghash_clmulni_intel snd_hda_codec_generic pcbc snd_soc_skl_ipc ath10k_core snd_hda_ext_core snd_soc_sst_dsp snd_soc_sst_ipc ath snd_soc_acpi snd_soc_core aesni_intel snd_compress mac80211(OE) ac97_bus aes_x86_64 snd_pcm_dmaengine sch_fq_codel crypto_simd glue_helper snd_hda_intel cryptd btusb uvcvideo snd_hda_codec btrtl dell_wmi intel_cstate videobuf2_vmalloc snd_hda_core dell_smbios intel_rapl_perf videobuf2_memops btbcm snd_hwdep btintel videobuf2_v4l2 dcdbas videobuf2_core bluetooth joydev snd_pcm input_leds hid_multitouch videodev wmi_bmof cfg80211(OE) serio_raw dell_wmi_descriptor
[    3.813853] Workqueue: ath10k_wq ath10k_core_register_work [ath10k_core]
[    3.813870]  ? ath10k_regd_update+0x2a0/0x2a0 [ath10k_core]
[    3.813872]  ath_regd_init+0x98/0x150 [ath]
[    3.813875]  ath10k_mac_register+0x5e3/0x8e0 [ath10k_core]
[    3.813879]  ath10k_core_register_work+0x651/0x7f0 [ath10k_core]
[    3.813923] Modules linked in: nls_iso8859_1 wl(POE) intel_rapl x86_pkg_temp_thermal intel_powerclamp coretemp kvm_intel kvm ath10k_pci snd_hda_codec_realtek(+) dell_laptop snd_soc_skl irqbypass crct10dif_pclmul crc32_pclmul ghash_clmulni_intel snd_hda_codec_generic pcbc snd_soc_skl_ipc ath10k_core snd_hda_ext_core snd_soc_sst_dsp snd_soc_sst_ipc ath snd_soc_acpi snd_soc_core aesni_intel snd_compress mac80211(OE) ac97_bus aes_x86_64 snd_pcm_dmaengine sch_fq_codel crypto_simd glue_helper snd_hda_intel cryptd btusb uvcvideo snd_hda_codec btrtl dell_wmi intel_cstate videobuf2_vmalloc snd_hda_core dell_smbios intel_rapl_perf videobuf2_memops btbcm snd_hwdep btintel videobuf2_v4l2 dcdbas videobuf2_core bluetooth joydev snd_pcm input_leds hid_multitouch videodev wmi_bmof cfg80211(OE) serio_raw dell_wmi_descriptor
[    3.813962] Workqueue: ath10k_wq ath10k_core_register_work [ath10k_core]
[    3.813976]  ? ath10k_regd_update+0x2a0/0x2a0 [ath10k_core]
[    3.813977]  ath_regd_init+0x98/0x150 [ath]
[    3.813980]  ath10k_mac_register+0x5e3/0x8e0 [ath10k_core]
[    3.813984]  ath10k_core_register_work+0x651/0x7f0 [ath10k_core]
[    3.814013] ath10k_pci 0000:3a:00.0: failed to register ieee80211: -22
[    3.814015] ath10k_pci 0000:3a:00.0: could not register to mac80211 (-22)
```

Comment: this might help https://askubuntu.com/questions/929027

Comment: Please edit your question to show the result of the terminal command: `sudo modprobe ath10k_pci && dmesg | grep ath`

Comment: @Kulfy The blacklist part is not needed. The firmware part is probably needed.

Comment: Please see https://askubuntu.com/questions/425155/my-wireless-wifi-connection-does-not-work-what-information-is-needed-to-diagnos and run the wireless script, then do `cat wireless-info.txt | nc termbin.com 9999` Post the URL from terminal

Comment: @Jeremy31 Ok, the outcome is https://termbin.com/l3ug

Comment: do `sudo apt remove bcmwl-kernel-source` reboot and run the script again

Comment: @Jeremy31 It did not work :-(
But, luckily, the latest Ubuntu kernel seems to fix this issue.

Comment: I know that a "me too" does not help, but I have the same issue, with the same hardware and same Ubuntu version. In my case, the wifi disappears when the laptop wakes up from sleeping mode or on a fresh boot **after** I've been using the laptop for a long time, somehow I associate the problem to heating issues. For me, it is not a persistent problem, though. The "non-scientific" way I found to fix it, is to leave the laptop switched off for several minutes, and start it again.

Comment: I solved it with [this response](https://askubuntu.com/a/1157429/412904) on Ubuntu 18.04 Kernel 5.0....

Answer (score 0):

Code:

```
sudo apt remove bcmwl-kernel-source && sudo apt install git dkms
git clone -b extended https://github.com/lwfinger/rtlwifi_new.git
sudo dkms add ./rtlwifi_new
sudo dkms install rtlwifi-new/0.6
```

Reboot.
If you notice weak signal try

```
sudo modprobe -r rtl8723de && sleep 5 && sudo modprobe rtl8723de ant_sel=1
```

and see if it is better, if not do

```
sudo modprobe -r rtl8723de && sleep 5 && sudo modprobe rtl8723de ant_sel=2
```

If that doesn't work I can suggest one more thing:
You will have to copy and paste the Wifi - Adapter from another computer or via the internet and install it. I do not know how to do this way, but maybe if you do some research you will find an answer.

Comment: Thanks for your help, but it hasn't work. No Wi-Fi adapter is found, yet. And yes, your second suggestion sounds good, but I have no clue how to get a Wi-Fi adapter from another computer (how should this be called?), even though I've already spent quite some time looking for a solution to my problem :-(

Comment: As you can see above, his is not a Realtek rtl8723de device; it is an Atheros QCA6174. This answer will be entirely ineffective.

Answer (score 0):

Update: the same behavior has erratically happened over and over again ever since, mostly - but not always - following an update of Ubuntu. I've recently realized that, at least for me, the solution consists of simply shutting down the laptop and restarting it. Strangely enough, rebooting it is NOT sufficient.

Comment: Maybe this is related: [https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=202541]

Answer (score 0):

After a lot of searching, I finally found out that the issue is related to Killer Wifi Driver. It was easy to fix using the **[instructions](https://support.killernetworking.com/knowledge-base/killer-ax1650-in-debian-ubuntu-16-04/) on the official Killer support page**. It lists the following commands.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:canonical-hwe-team/backport-iwlwifi
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install backport-iwlwifi-dkms
reboot
```

Although it is listed for ubuntu 16.04, it worked for 18.04 as well for me.

Comment: Ubuntu have really good support pages, Killer have nothing to do with this case. Also you can find the problem is solved in original questions comments.

Comment: @PasiSuominen had personally tried the solution in the above answers and found that it didn't work for me. The issue was with the wifi driver which could be solved this way. I posted it here in case anyone else was struggling with the same.