# Dell XPS 15 7590: No Bluetooth with Killer AX1650 adapter in Ubunti 18.04.2

Tags: bluetooth, dell, xps

I followed [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1157427/dell-xps-7590-ubuntu-18-04-no-wifi-adapter-found/1157429#1157429) post and had excellent results for getting AX 1650 card to work.  I used a generic Kootek USB wifi dongle to get access to my wifi and was able to run all the commands on this really nice laptop and now have Wifi using the AX 1650 adapter.

The problem is, I cannot access Bluetooth. It does not show an adapter present in the GUI which just shows the button set to 'OFF'. Clicking on the button changes the color to orange for a minute and then it turns back.

Has anyone had this issue or know a way to backport bluetooth drivers?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

OK, so this seems to have gotten fixed but I'm not sure how.  I installed some more apps, played around with the tweak tool but what I think what actually fixed it was turning on Livepatch. Once I did, it offered some updates.  When I did a reboot due to an error I got when video player crashed, Bluetooth was working and labeled "On".  I wish I could have exactly retrace what I did but I wasn't actually trying to fix issue.  I hope someone can actually make a real contribution for this issue.  Best regards.