# Killer Wireless 1650 on Ubuntu 18.04 doesn't work

Tags: networking, drivers, 18.04, wireless, xps

I installed Ubuntu 18.04 on a Dell **XPS 15 7590** with a **Killer Wireless 1650 2x2 AX** Wifi card, but impossible to connect to wifi, with the following message : *No WiFi Adapter found*.

I found [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1157429/847530) which seems to work for some people, but not for me... The solution need an internet connection, and this is the current problem.

(The link doesn't work for now, so I put a screeshoot of instructions) 
[image]

So I cloned the repo from an another computer and transfer with USB stick :

```
$ git clone https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/iwlwifi/backport-iwlwifi.git
```

I installed *make* from the ubuntu iso, as Bernard advise [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/1168602/847530).

I continued to follow instructions :

```
$ make defconfig-iwlwifi-public
$ make -j4
```

Those commands seems to work, I only get the following message for both, at the beggining:

> make[5]: execvp: ./lxdialog/check/lxdialog.sh : Permission denied
>   make[5]: execvp: ./lxdialog/check/lxdialog.sh : Permission denied

And when I finally enter `$ sudo make install` I got this message :

> Building modules, stage 2.
>     MODPOST 6 modules
>     INSTALL /home/remi/wifi/backport-iwlwifi/compat/compat.ko
>   At main.c:160:
>   - SSL error:02001002:system library:fopen:No such file or directory: ../crypto/bio/bss_file.c:72
>   - SSL error:2006D080:BIO routines:BIO_new_file:no such file: ../crypto/bio/bss_file.c:79
>   sign-file: certs/signing_key.pem: No such file or directory
>     INSTALL /home/remi/wifi/backport-iwlwifi/drivers/net/wireless/intel/iwlwifi/iwlwifi.ko
>   At main.c:160:
>   - SSL error:02001002:system library:fopen:No such file or directory: ../crypto/bio/bss_file.c:72
>   - SSL error:2006D080:BIO routines:BIO_new_file:no such file: ../crypto/bio/bss_file.c:79
>   sign-file: certs/signing_key.pem: No such file or directory
>     INSTALL /home/remi/wifi/backport-iwlwifi/drivers/net/wireless/intel/iwlwifi/mvm/iwlmvm.ko
>   At main.c:160:
>   - SSL error:02001002:system library:fopen:No such file or directory: ../crypto/bio/bss_file.c:72
>   - SSL error:2006D080:BIO routines:BIO_new_file:no such file: ../crypto/bio/bss_file.c:79
>   sign-file: certs/signing_key.pem: No such file or directory
>     INSTALL /home/remi/wifi/backport-iwlwifi/drivers/net/wireless/intel/iwlwifi/xvt/iwlxvt.ko
>   At main.c:160:
>   - SSL error:02001002:system library:fopen:No such file or directory: ../crypto/bio/bss_file.c:72
>   - SSL error:2006D080:BIO routines:BIO_new_file:no such file: ../crypto/bio/bss_file.c:79
>   sign-file: certs/signing_key.pem: No such file or directory
>     INSTALL /home/remi/wifi/backport-iwlwifi/net/mac80211/mac80211.ko
>   At main.c:160:
>   - SSL error:02001002:system library:fopen:No such file or directory: ../crypto/bio/bss_file.c:72
>   - SSL error:2006D080:BIO routines:BIO_new_file:no such file: ../crypto/bio/bss_file.c:79
>   sign-file: certs/signing_key.pem: No such file or directory
>     INSTALL /home/remi/wifi/backport-iwlwifi/net/wireless/cfg80211.ko
>   At main.c:160:
>   - SSL error:02001002:system library:fopen:No such file or directory: ../crypto/bio/bss_file.c:72
>   - SSL error:2006D080:BIO routines:BIO_new_file:no such file: ../crypto/bio/bss_file.c:79
>   sign-file: certs/signing_key.pem: No such file or directory
>     DEPMOD  5.0.0-23-generic
>   Warning: modules_install: missing 'System.map' file. Skipping depmod.
>   make[1]: execvp: ./scripts/blacklist.sh : Permission non accordée
>   Makefile.real:104: recipe for target 'install' failed
>   make[1]: *** [install] Error 127
>   Makefile:40: recipe for target 'install' failed
>   make: *** [install] Error 2

Please, what can I do ? If I buy a USB to LAN adapter, can I have a connection ? Or it will be the same ? I can't found any solutions.

**EDIT**:
I finally bought a USB-C to LAN adapter, and I can have an Internet connection. I updated and upgraded packages, and I repeated again all the commands, but it still doesn't works. The `sudo make install` still display *ssl errors*, but not the *make install error* anymore.
What am I missing ? What can I do, please ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://askubuntu.com/questions/1157427/dell-xps-7590-ubuntu-18-04-no-wifi-adapter-found

Comment: A USB to LAN adapter would let you connect to an Ethernet connection that 'should' then let you get to the Internet to get the requisites for the driver build.  However, each USB Ethernet adapter is different, so without knowing which USB Ethernet adapter you are looking at it'll be hard to tell if it'll work for your system

Comment: Ok, how could I know which one buy for my system? Is there something specific on adapter I should care about?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I finally suceedeed, so I summarize the detailed instructions, hoping it can help some people.

1. Apparently it's important to turn **off** your **secure boot** before the following actions.
2. To fix the *No Wifi Adapter found*, you need a Internet connection. If you have an Ethernet port on your laptop it's good, else, you have to use an adapter. Personnaly I used a USB-C to LAN adapter and it works.
3. Once you have a connection, you can update and upgrade packages (Maybe not necessary, but always good) `sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade`.
4. Execute all of the commands on [this article](https://support.killernetworking.com/knowledge-base/killer-ax1650-in-debian-ubuntu-16-04/):

```
sudo apt-get install git
sudo apt-get install build-essential

git clone https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/iwlwifi/backport-iwlwifi.git
cd backport-iwlwifi
make defconfig-iwlwifi-public
make -j4
sudo make install

sudo git clone git://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/firmware/linux-firmware.git
cd linux-firmware
sudo cp iwlwifi-* /lib/firmware/
```

5. Before reboot, execute this command to **update initramfs** `update-initramfs -u`.
6. Now you can reboot.

You should be able to access wifi parameters now.
Thanks.

Comment: Important note- I think you have to be running the target kernel version when you do the "make" commands. (I ran into this and it wasn't obvious what was wrong.)

Comment: the patcwork.kernel.org patch was not necessary for me at this point. I suspect it's been merged/upstreamed. Additionally, it did not look like it would apply cleanly at this point.

Comment: This works for ubuntu 16.04, but if you try to do the same in Ubuntu 18.04 the system freezes in the login screen.

Comment: I did it with Ubuntu 18.04 !

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same issue after installing 18.04.2. Since I did not have network connection on that machine I installed 18.04.4 in which the problem has been fixed.

Comment: Yes, for the first months, I had to execute previous commands after each kernel update. But since a few months (I guess 18.04.4), everything is good with the network.
However, there are some problems about battery and CPU overheating... 
Personnally, I use commands like powertop everyday to improve that, but it's not perfect !