# XPS13 7390 wireless stopped working on 19.10 after update yesterday

Tags: networking, drivers, updates

Yes, I am fairly new to Linux. Long story short, I have the XPS13 dev. Went from 18.04 LTS to 19.04 and all working. THen upgraded to 19.10 last week and wireless stopped working. I have the Killer 1435.

I tried stuff from these sites with multiple reboots and it suddenly started working. Unfortunately I was so frustrated (and stupid) I did not log what I did to get it working.

https://support.killernetworking.com/knowledge-base/killer-ax1650-in-debian-ubuntu-16-04/

https://support.killernetworking.com/knowledge-base/wi-fi-issues-with-1435-1535-1525-on-debian-ubuntu-and-arch/

https://wireless.wiki.kernel.org/en/users/drivers/iwlwifi/core_release

[Killer Wireless 1650 on Ubuntu 18.04 doesn't work](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1172026/killer-wireless-1650-on-ubuntu-18-04-doesnt-work)

I did an update yesterday (sudo apt update && sudo apt full-upgrade -y) and after a reboot, wireless network stopped working. I have a LAN adapter and using it now.

If I go to SOFTWARE & UPDATES | ADDITIONAL DRIVERS, I see "Intel Corporation: Unknown: THis device is not working".  There are three options. 
-Using iwlwifi driver backport in DKMS format for backport-iwlwifi-dkms (Open SOurce) 
    *This is grayed out and I can not choose it to even test
-Continue using a manaully installed driver
    *This I can click, but after reboot, it is unchecked.
-Do not use this device
    *This is always selected.

Any help would be GREATLY appreciated.

Comment: Please edit your question to show the result of these terminal commands: `sudo dkms status` and also: `sudo modprobe iwlwifi && dmesg | grep iwl` Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: I have the same problem.

sudo dkms status
  backport-iwlwifi, 8042, 5.3.0-19-generic, x86_64: installed

sudo modprobe iwlwifi && dmesg | grep iwl                                                                                                                           
[   30.908489] Loading modules backported from iwlwifi
[   30.908490] iwlwifi-stack-public:master:8042:654c426c

Answer (score 1):

I was in the same situation, and i saw that despite the successfull upgrade to 19.10, the kernel was still on 4.15 !

So i just made :

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall linux-generic
```

And boom ! It worked !