# Dell XPS 15 7590 lost WiFi

Tags: networking, 19.10, xps

A couple of months ago, I got a new XPS 15 (7590).

I immediately installed Ubuntu 19.10, and had no problems, everything worked great.

Yesterday, after not using it for several days, I attempted to do so, and I was surprised I had no internet.  I thought maybe my configuration lost WiFi password, and I'd have to re-enter it.

But no, when I went to do that, I got message that the WiFi was not detected.

ifconfig -a shows only lo.

It seems the WiFi driver is missing.

Is this some kind of regression?  Did a kernel or firmware upgrade break my WiFi?

Any clues?

Thanks!

Edit:
Add new info:

```
$ lapci -knn|grep Net
3b:00.0. Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:2723] (rev 1a)
         Subsystem Bigfoot Networks, Inc. Device [1a56:1654]
```

Sorry it took so long!

Also, `rfkill list` doesn't seem to do anything

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; rfkill list` terminal command.

Comment: Any further updates?  I'm stillll stuck.

Comment: Did you install any drivers before?

Comment: I just did a full clean install of 19.10.  it worked great initially.  Then, a few weeks ago, it just stopped.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; rfkill list` terminal command. The full output, not a part of it.

Comment: I wiped and reinstalled 19.10, and it seems fine now.  Still no idea what was going on, but I''m ok now.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same laptop, and the same problem when I installed Ubuntu 18.04 the first time.

The only solution I found is the following :

```
sudo apt-get install git
sudo apt-get install build-essential

git clone 
https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/iwlwifi/backport- 
iwlwifi.git
cd backport-iwlwifi
make defconfig-iwlwifi-public
make -j4
sudo make install

sudo git clone 
git://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/firmware/linux-firmware.git
cd linux-firmware
sudo cp iwlwifi-* /lib/firmware/
```

Of course, you need internet connection to do it. You have to buy an Ethernet/USB-C adapter.

Sometimes, the probleme come back after updating linux kernel packages, and I have to reproduce the same commands.

I hope the problem will be fixed soon, maybe with Ubuntu 20.04 !

(Original answer [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1172026/killer-wireless-1650-on-ubuntu-18-04-doesnt-work))