# Wifi network is disabled

Tags: networking, 20.04

During the installation of Ubuntu 20.04 I remember the field where networks were supposed to show up actually showed my device (QCA6174 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter) instead of the available networks. I remember clicking it thinking I would select the wifi network later on.
When I run `lshw -c network` it shows `*-network DISABLED` for my wifi card.

I've tried looking for additional software within Ubuntu which shows there is no additional software. I've tried resetting the network management service and also manually creating a .yaml file using netplan. None of these options have worked.
I am able to connect to the internet through wired connection.
When I click the wifi options in Ubuntu it says unavailable, yet it seems like it's searching for networks. Ultimately it finds none.

[image]

Comment: Hi and welcome. Please do not show pictures of text include all text in the body of the question. Does the wireless work if you boot from the live media and choose try instead of install?

Comment: This is another problem, I am unable to boot from live USB after installing Ubuntu. I enabled secure boot and went through the same steps today to install the initial Ubuntu image, now it won't let me boot to USB anymore.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Qualcomm Atheros QCA6174 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter \[168c:003e\] (rev 32) can't enable wi-fi](https://askubuntu.com/questions/929027/qualcomm-atheros-qca6174-802-11ac-wireless-network-adapter-168c003e-rev-32)

Comment: Secure boot needs to be off.

Comment: @singrium this removed the wifi option in the Ubuntu settings, which means is seems to have done something but it hasn't quite fixed the problem.
when running the 'lshw -c network' command it now shows it isnt disabled anymore, but it doesn't work.