# Qualcomm Atheros QCA6174 on Samsung Galaxy Book 12 - No wifi

Tags: networking, drivers, wireless, xubuntu, atheros

I've just installed **Xubuntu 22.04** on a Samsung Galaxy Book 12 with Qualcomm Atheros QCA6174 and it doesn't work. (Also does not work with **Kali 2022.2**) the output of the commands are identical on both images

I followed this link to try to resolve the issue on my own, but with no luck:

> [Qualcomm Atheros QCA6174 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter [168c:003e] (rev 32) can't enable wi-fi](https://askubuntu.com/questions/929027/qualcomm-atheros-qca6174-802-11ac-wireless-network-adapter-168c003e-rev-32)

I have already downloaded https://github.com/kvalo/ath10k-firmware to the target pc

*the following output is hand typed as the target pc has no internet, there may be discrepancies*

Output of :
lspci -nnk | grep -iA2 net

```
01:00.0 Network Controller [0280]: Qualcomm Atheros QCA 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter [168c:003e] (rev32)
     Subsystem: Samsung Electronics Co Ltd QCA6174 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter [144d:c14f]
     Kernel driver in use: ath10k_pci
     Kernel modules: ath10kpci
```

Output of: dmesg | grep ath

```
[  277.827172] ath10k_pci 0000:01:00.0: enabling device (0000 -> 0002)
[  277.829061] ath10k_pci 0000:01:00.0: pci irq msi oper_irq_mode 2 irq_mode 0 reset_mode 0
[  279.127016] ath10k_pci 0000:01:00.0: qca6174 hw3.2 target 0x05030000 chip_id 0x00340aff sub 144d:c14f
[  279.127022] ath10k_pci 0000:01:00.0: kconfig debug 0 debugfs 1 tracing 1 dfs 0 testmode 0
[  279.127442] ath10k_pci 0000:01:00.0: firmware ver WLAN.RM.4.4.1-00140-QCARMSWPZ-1 api 6 features wowlan,ignore-otp,mfp crc32 29eb8ca1
[  279.318796] ath10k_pci 0000:01:00.0: board_file api 2 bmi_id N/A crc32 4ac0889b
[  279.409720] ath10k_pci 0000:01:00.0: htt-ver 3.60 wmi-op 4 htt-op 3 cal otp max-sta 32 raw 0 hwcrypto 1
[  279.487519] ath: EEPROM regdomain: 0x5f
[  279.487523] ath: EEPROM indicates we should expect a direct regpair map
[  279.487524] ath: invalid regulatory domain/country code 0x5f
[  279.487524] ath: Invalid EEPROM contents
[  279.487528] ath10k_pci 0000:01:00.0: failed to initialise regulatory: -22
[  279.487531] ath10k_pci 0000:01:00.0: could not register to mac80211 (-22)
```

rfkill list all output:

```
0: hci: Bluetooth
     Soft blocked: no
     Hard blocked: no
```

**(bluetooth does work)**

thanks in advance